# Where is the project directory structure configuration stored in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working with a multi-module project in IntelliJ (was imported from Eclipse) I am wondering where the directory structure configuration is stored in IntelliJ so that I can declare the **source**/**resource**/**test-source**/**test-resource** roots instead of having to right click and select and mark directories 40+ times. A task I do not relish after invalidating caches.